# react-native [iOS] RCTAssert RCTFormatError 165 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: typeAnnotation

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, build, crashlytics

[iOS] app is working fine on simulator or device when I run it directly, But when I generate an archive it's crashing.
With the help of Crashlytics, I found the issue here

```
Fatal Exception: RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: typeAnnotation
Unhandled JS Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: typeAnnotation, stack: <unknown>@1383:17088 v@2:1473 <unknown>@1382:425 v@2:1473 <unknown>@1381:339 v@2:1473 <unknown>@1374:6338 v@2:1473 <unknown>@1373:303 v@2:1473 <unknown>@650:7881 v@2:1473 <unknown>@437:237 v@2:1473 <unknown>@408:255 v@2:1473 <unknown>@6:57 v@2:1473 d@2:875 global code@1711:3
```

```
RCTAssert.m - Line 165
RCTFormatError + 165
```

**React Native version:**

```
System:
    OS: macOS 11.0.1
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
    Memory: 21.23 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.13.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.12.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.0 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 14.2, DriverKit 20.0, macOS 11.0, tvOS 14.2, watchOS 7.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 26, 28, 29, 30
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 30.0.2
      System Images: android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283
    Xcode: 12.2/12B45b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_275 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
    react-native: 0.63.3 => 0.63.3 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

[image]

Comment: How can we verify that the bundles are binding in the archive, I think it could be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed by adding
`import 'react-native-gesture-handler';`
to the index.js

Secondly, I removed an auto imported thing from babel which is causing the crash.

- removed this `import { cloneDeep } from '@babel/types';`

Auto import from babel is the main crash.

Comment: even though I added `import 'react-native-gesture-handler'` in index.js still my app is getting crashed? In which file I should remove `import { cloneDeep } from '@babel/types`?

Comment: Search globally, there should not be import from ```babel```

Comment: Yes, I did. But i didn't find any import. crash is happening when I am trying to install the `codepush` updates. If there are no updates form `codepush` then there will be no crash. Any alternatives to try?

Comment: I think you should have to review all the imports